# React Hook Forms Register with YupResolver not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to a rather simple login form using react-hook-form and yup resolver.
The problem I'm having is that the register function doesn't seem to be working and I honestly ran out of ideas. I'm fairly new to ReactJS so I apologize in advance if the issue seems (and I hope it is) something trivial.

My yup object looks like this:

```
export const LoginModelSchema = object({
  email: string().email().required('Please enter a valid email'),
  password: string().required().matches(
    /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/,
    "Must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and One Special Case Character"
  ),
});

export type LoginModelType = InferType<typeof LoginModelSchema>;
```

And my form object looks like this:

```
interface ILoginModel {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<ILoginModel>({
        resolver: yupResolver(LoginModelSchema),
    });

const submit = async (data: LoginModelType) => {
        const response = await mutateAsync(data);
        console.log('api response', response);
    };
```

```
<>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
                <Box mt={3}>
                    <Divider />
                </Box>

                <Stack>
                    <Box>
                        <CustomFormLabel>Email</CustomFormLabel>
                        <CustomTextField {...register('email')} variant="outlined" fullWidth />
                        {errors.email && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.email.message}</p>}
                    </Box>
                    <Box>
                        <CustomFormLabel htmlFor="password">Password</CustomFormLabel>
                        <CustomTextField
                            {...register('password')}
                            type="password"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                        />
                        {errors.password && (
                            <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors.password.message}</p>
                        )}
                    </Box>
                    <Stack
                        justifyContent="space-between"
                        direction="row"
                        alignItems="center"
                        my={2}
                    >
                        <FormGroup>
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={<CustomCheckbox defaultChecked />}
                                label="Remeber this Device"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Typography
                            component={Link}
                            to="/auth/forgot-password"
                            fontWeight="500"
                            sx={{
                                textDecoration: 'none',
                                color: 'primary.main',
                            }}
                        >
                            Forgot Password ?
                        </Typography>
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>
                <Box>
                    <Button
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        size="large"
                        fullWidth
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </form>
        </>
```

And everytime the submit is clicked the validator this happens:

[image]

Implement a simple react-hook-form

Comment: You will need to provide the JSX code with `handleSubmit` and input registration in order for us to assist you.

Comment: I have updated the post and added the jsx part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day the problem was the control CustomTextField that came with the template Modernize from AdminMart. Using Material TextField solved the issue.